# Parâmetros default

Tags: php, parâmetros

Estou tendo um problema com os parâmetros em uma função PHP.

Por exemplo:

```
function exemplo($par1 = 1, $par2 = 2) {
    return $par1 . " - " . $par2;
}

exemplo();        // 1 - 2
exemplo(3);       // 3 - 2
exemplo(3, 4);    // 3 - 4
exemplo(null, 4); //   - 4
```

Na última chamada, estou tentando passar apenas o **segundo** parâmetro e manter o primeiro como *default*, mas não é o que acontece (a variável fica com valor `null`).

É possível alcançar o comportamento desejado neste caso?

Answer (score 5):

Não tem como 'pular' o primeiro parâmetro, mas o que você pode fazer é uma condição para o `null` ser trabalhado com o parâmetro.

```
function exemplo( $par1 = 1 , $par2 = 2 )
{
    return ( ! isset( $par1 ) ? 1 : $par1 ) . " - " . $par2;
}

exemplo( null , 4 );
```

**output** : `1 - 4`

<sub>Atualizei a resposta para usar operador ternário em uma linha.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

O PHP [**ainda não possui parâmetros nomeados**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params), assim como há no [**Python**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls), portanto, o que pode ser feito (*além das alternativas já mencionadas*) é passar um *array* como parâmetro para a função.

> Porém existem certas *desvantagens*, como os parâmetros disponíveis
> não são documentados na [assinatura](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.typehinting.php), é necessário olhar
> no código da função para descobrir, outra desvantagem é que requer mais código
> para implementar, porque o valores padrões devem ser *mesclados* com
> os valores indicados na chamada da função.
>
> A implementação inicial dos parâmetros nomeados pode ser visto [**aqui**](https://github.com/nikic/php-src/commit/1f38d98134b87ff87625c212d01ff29494ff5503).

Exemplo:

```
function exemplo(array $args) {
    $pares = array('par1' => 1, 'par2' => 2);
    $args = array_merge($pares, array_intersect_key($args, $pares));
    list($par1, $par2) = array_values($args);
    
    return $par1 .' - '. $par2;
}
```

Utilização:

```
echo exemplo([]) . "\n";                         // 1 - 2
echo exemplo(['par1' => 3]) . "\n";              // 3 - 2
echo exemplo(['par1' => 3, 'par2' => 4]) . "\n"; // 3 - 4
echo exemplo(['par2' => 4]) . "\n";              // 1 - 4
```

[**`DEMO`**](http://ideone.com/GO7Xze)

Comment: Para ficar menos gambistico, http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: @ÉdipoCostaRebouças Não acho que seja gambiarra, até porque a [página do PHP](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params) que citei, futuramente pretende adotar uma sintaxe parecida com está, veja a seção *Open questions*, aproveite e veja também a seção `func_* and call_user_func_array`.

Comment: Entendi o seu ponto, acho que você poderia citar o named params de forma mais clara na sua resposta, ao invés de usar "este recurso".

Answer (score 2):

A melhor maneira de se tratar esse tipo de situação é utilizar a função [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php).
A utilização é simples:
Você declara a função sem nenhum parâmetro e dentro da função utilize o `func_get_args()` para coletar os parâmetros passados. Um exemplo seria:

```
function exemplo() {
   $parametros = func_get_args();
   if(!empty($parametros)) {
       $parametro1 = $parametros[0];
       $parametro2 = $parametros[1];
       ...
       $parametroN = $parametros[N];
   }
}

exemplo();
exemplo('arg1', 'arg2');
exemplo('arg1', 'arg2', ..., 'argn');
```

Comment: Veja o que a de novo no PHP, existe um jeito mais moderno de fazer isso. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Answer (score 2):

```
function exemplo($par1 = null, $par2 = null) {
    $_par1 = null === $par1 ? 1 : $par1;
    $_par2 = null === $par2 ? 2 : $par2;
    return $_par1 . ' - ' . $_par2;
}
```

Comportamento consistente se você usar `exemplo(null, null)`

Comment: Se o padrão é `$par1 = null, $par2 = null`, porque passar `exemplo(null, null)`? Basta `exemplo()` ou tirar o default da função `exemplo($par1 , $par2 )`

Comment: se o segundo parâmetro for o resultado de uma função, esse comportamento é útil, pois esse resultado pode ser null.

Comment: Não quis dizer isso... Sua resposta está correta e mais completa que a minha por sinal, a OBS que fiz foi que a chamada `exemplo()` já faz uso dos valores padrões sme precisar passar `NULL , NULL`.

Comment: No comentário eu respondi sua pergunta: "porque passar exemplo(null, null)?".

Answer (score 1):

Olha, não digo que seja o mais correto, porém, sempre que preciso usar parâmetros com valores *default*, tento deixá-los por último na função, da seguinte forma:

```
function exemplo ($arg1, $arg2 = null) {
    // Corpo da função
}
```

Desta forma fica fácil de controlar, parâmetros obrigatórios devem ser passados primeiro, já os que possuem valores *default*, por último.

As chamadas à função ficariam assim:

```
exemplo($arg1);
exemplo($arg1, $arg2);
```

Há uma maneira nova de fazer o que foi proposto, mas como requisito, você deve ter instalado o **PHP 5.6** ou superior, que seria:

```
function somar (...$numeros) {
    $soma = 0;
    foreach ($numeros as $numero) {
        $soma += $numero;
    }
    return $soma;
}
```

**...$numeros** - Indica que a função irá ter um número variável de parâmetros, e estes serão armazenados nessa variável do tipo *Array*

As chamadas à função ficariam assim:

```
somar(1, 3, 5);
somar(5, 7, 18, 20, 63, 72, 12, 54);
```

Comment: Eu sempre deixo os opcionais por último. Quanto aos parâmetros utilizando `...` é só utilizar `func_get_args`...